# How do I get the Android Bundle/Packager Identifier

Tags: android, package, bundle, identifier

I am writing a library for android that need the bundle identifier
I can not figure out how to get the bundle identifier or equivalent for my running android application.

I think it is related to the Intent object by can not figure it out.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean the package name for your app?  You can use Activity.getPackageName().

[getPackageName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getPackageName%28%29)

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```